# url undefined when using Ext.data.Model

Tags: extjs4.1

i'm working in a small project and i want to use the ext.data.model, the thing is that i having some problems when i want to load some data.

here is the model declaration.

```
Ext.define('Model.Item',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'code', 'description'],


    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'Handlers/Item.ashx',
            create: 'Handlers/Item.ashx?action=create',
            destroy: 'Handlers/Item.ashx?action=delete',
            update: 'Handlers/Item.ashx?action=update'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data',
            allowSingle: false
        }
    }
});
```

and i using it with a jsonstore like this.

```
new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                    storeId: 'mainStore',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    model: 'Model.Item'
                })
```

binging it with a grid, before i wasnt using model, and was working just fine. no i cant get it to work.

i get url is undefined exception in ext-all.js

```
    urlAppend : function(url, string) {
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(string)) {
            return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + string;
        }


        return url;
    },
```

this funcion is called from Ext.data.proxy.Server in the buildUrl function.

well any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly by using `JsonStore` you are overriding the proxy definition of your model - JsonStore adds its own proxy config, and if such exist for the store it won't look for one in the model. Try replacing `Ext.data.JsonStore` with `Ext.data.Store`.

Comment: i have not declared a proxy in the jsonstore. but debugging extjs i found that the store loads as this.proxy.read(xxx) instead of search for me.model.proxy (if exists)...

Comment: If I understand you correctly then yes - JsonStore automatically adds a proxy, which was called instead of that of the model. So is your problem solved?

Comment: not yet... i want to define the proxy in the model.. as it is exposed in the doc...

Comment: And using `Ext.data.Store` doesn't help?

Comment: i didnt try with Ext.data.Store, i suppose that its the same as JsonStore... i will try now. thanks for your time! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `JsonStore` you are overriding the proxy definition of your model - `JsonStore` adds its own proxy config:

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.JsonStore',  {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.json',

    …

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            proxy: {
                type  : 'ajax',
                reader: 'json',
                writer: 'json'
            }
        }, config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```

and if such exist for the store it won't look for one in the model.

To solve this, replace `Ext.data.JsonStore` with `Ext.data.Store`.